# Inserting page number on the landscape page

Tags: page-numbering, landscape

I inserted a landscaped page in my document to containing large table. The pagination before, and after the landscape page appear correctly: 13, 15.

However, the page number on the landscaped page did not appear, just continued on following page.

The following code reproduce the issue:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\blindtext

\afterpage{
    \clearpage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{landscape}
        \centering 
        \begin{table}
        \caption{A summary of previous studies and methods employed \textit{(*N/A = Not available)}.} 
        \label{distance-duration}
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lccXcccr}
            \toprule
            \thead{Author(s)}  & \thead{modes\\ detected} & \thead{Classifier used}  & \thead{Features}   & \thead{Population}  & \thead{External\\ Data used}  & \thead{Period} & \thead{Accuracy} \\
            \midrule
        Author 1 & 4 & DT & distance, velocity \& acceleration statistics & 45 users [GeoLife] & No &6 months & 72.80\%\\
        \midrule
    Author 2 &5 & Fuzzy engine &  speed acceleration statistics &4,882 users &No &6.65 days & N/A\\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
         \hfill
        \end{table} 
    \end{landscape}
    \clearpage
}

\chapter{Body}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `\thispagestyle{empty}` as part of your landscape page construction. That *removes* the headers and footers, so no page number will show up. Remove this and you'll see the page number in the usual spot.

If you wish to adjust the placement of the page number (since the page is in landscape), you could define a new page style or position it elsewhere using [`eso-pic`](//ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic). Using the latter suggestion, you can still use `\thispagestyle{empty}` and place the following additional code directly after it:

```
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \raisebox{\dimexpr.5\paperheight-.5\height}{%
      \makebox[.9\paperwidth][r]{%
        \rotatebox{90}{\thepage}
      }% \makebox
    }% \raisebox
  }% \AtPageCenter
}% \AddToShipoutPictureBG*
```

The above code puts `\thepage` 90% down the page. You can play around with different options of `.9\paperwidth` and place the page number to suit your needs.

[image]

Comment: Ah, yes it appears now. it need to change its position now.

Comment: @arilwan: I've added some code that you can use to position and place the page number.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer.